# Android Emulator Black Screen (Emulation engine failed) - Riot Vanguard

Tags: android, android-studio

Feel like a lot of people will run into this after Valorant being released but running the emulator just gives me a black screen with "Engine emulation failed" using Android Studio 4 and everything updated. Disabling Riot Vanguard fixes this.

Any idea on how to have both running? So I don't have to reboot every time.

Answer (score 0):

Open task manager and go into ‘startup' section and disable Vangaurd. This will prevent Vangaurd to start on boot, and only launch Vangaurd when you start the game.
This setting will not work on the first time itself, and might ask a restart if you try launching the game after disabling the service. But it will be effective afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Disable Riot Vanguard solved the problem